# powershell script that reads the last modified date of a folder

Tags: excel, date

I need a script that reads the last modified date of a file and by whom it was modified and outputs to excel. I found a script that changes the modification date.

```
$a = get-date
$b = Get-ChildItem "C:\Intel" -recurse | ? { !$_.psiscontainer }
foreach ($i in $b)
{
    $i.LastWriteTime = $a 
}

$b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the LastWriteTime by checking the LastWriteTime proprty of a file.

```
get-childitem * | select FullName,LastWriteTime,Owner
```

You can check the owner of a file which may or may not be the last person to modify depending on the file type. Some office files will change owner to the last person to write to them but I don't know that this is reliable.

```
get-childitem * | ForEach-Object {get-acl $_ | select owner}
```

NTFS doesn't log the last person to modify a file. You can either turn on auditing and check the system audit eventlog or look into the filesystemwatcher class and build a custom script that watches for changes to a folder. (Warning: this may cause performance issues.)